# How to mock or disable location.assign while unit testing in angular 4. Karma instance moving to assign parameter route

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine, spy

I am trying to write unit test for logout method:

```
logout(): Observable<boolean> {
    ...
    location.assign('/Login');
    ...
    return Observable.of(false);
}
```

When karma getting line `location.assign('/Login');` test result page moving away and writing 'NOT FOUND'.

I was trying to use spyOn:

```
spyOn(location,'assign').and.callFake(()=> true);
```

But getting error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : assign is not declared writable or has no setter
```

How to mock or disable location.assign method for unit test run?

Comment: here's the article how to do this https://medium.com/@sergeyfetiskin/testing-browser-window-location-in-angular-application-e4e8388508ff